# How to make this sentence sound like a native?

Tags: translation, word-usage

I was writing a diary about the things which happened today, and suddenly faced this problem.
Is it natural to write: "문제의 정답을 쓰는 방법을 아는데 수자를 쓰기 잘못했어요" to represent the meaning? Or are there any better sentences that can describe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you wanted to say was to the effect of "I know how to solve the problem, but got the answer wrong." If this is not what you wanted, let me know.

(1) 문제 푸는 과정은 아는데 답이 틀렸어요. I know how to solve the problem, but got the answer wrong.

(2) 문제 푸는 과정은 아는데 계산이 틀렸어요. I know how to solve the problem, but got the calculation wrong.

(3) 문제 푸는 과정은 아는데 숫자 표기가 틀렸어요. I know how to solve the problem, but got the **numeral system** wrong (some countries use commas instead of decimals, etc.)

(4) 문제 푸는 과정도 이해하고 정답까지 추리했는데 답안지에 틀리게 적었어요. I knew how to solve the problem and came up with the correct answer, but made a mistake writing down the answer on the answer sheet.